# how to use same page web primefaces once in view and other time in edit mode

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, primefaces

i have a table That shows me data about element X, in EACH ROW of table, i include a button to navigate to Appropriate page of the element's X.

I want that page i navigate to, be in view (Just view data Regarding element of X) and in --other time in edit .depending connected user.

please, somebody give me idea about this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you asking, but is it possible to make the components of that page readonly like so:

```
<p:inputText readonly = "#{bean.makeReadonly()}" value = "HelloWorld"/>
```

Then in the backing bean of your method makeReadonly, you will have

```
    if (userId = '1') 
     readonly = false //or "false" (sometime booleans don't work right for some reason) 
    else 
   readonly = true
```

If this doesn't work you can do the same thing with the attribute 'disabled'

Comment: Thank's brother,i solve my issue with rendered attribute.Thank's a lot